# How to check temperature of Mobo/CPU in OS X on intel iMac

Tags: mac-osx, physical-environment

I have an intel iMac that I think is overheating.  Is there a program that I can run in OS X that will give me the readings of the built in temperature sensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### iStat

Will allow you to monitor temperature and usage http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatmenus/

Answer (score 0):

Check out iStat Nano or iStat Pro from [iSlayer](http://www.islayer.com/apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Temperature Monitor http://www.bresink.de/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html